# SQLSRV call a stored procedure in SQL server

Tags: php, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm totally new at this, Just do 'cause of boss request. So i have some issue wanna ask.

This is result when i call SP in SQL

[image]

Below is code to calling a SP in php

```
$ma_dvcs = 'OL';
$ngay = '01/2/2015';
$ma_kho = 'BPOL01';
$ma_nhvt = '';
$ma_vt = '24110012A2140850';
$kieu = '1';
$query = "{call Tondaulist (@p_Ma_Dvcs_List = ?,@p_Ngay = ?,@p_Ma_Kho = ?,@p_Ma_Nh_Vt = ?,@p_Ma_Vt = ?,@p_Kieu = ?)}";

$params = array(
                array(&$ma_dvcs, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array(&$ngay, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array(&$ma_kho, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array(&$ma_nhvt, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array(&$ma_vt, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN),
                array(&$kieu, SQLSRV_PARAM_IN)
                );

$smtp = sqlsrv_prepare($conn, $query, $params);

if( $smtp === false )
{
     echo "Error in executing statement 3.\n";
     die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}
$rows = sqlsrv_execute($smtp);
var_dump($rows);die;
$arr[] = sqlsrv_fetch_array($rows,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
```

SQLSRV exec var_dump return true but i cant fetch anything and it keep giving error:

```
The active result for the query contains no fields
```

Or

```
sqlsrv_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given
```

So i wanna know is SP working the same like function in php or not? If yes, can it return an array or can just return boolean and how to get that array?

Thank in advance

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your query to this

```
$query = "EXEC Tondaulist @p_Ma_Dvcs_List = ?,@p_Ngay = ?,@p_Ma_Kho = ?,@p_Ma_Nh_Vt = ?,@p_Ma_Vt = ?,@p_Kieu = ?";
```

This won't return an "array" SQL doesn't support arrays, but it will return a result set
You also need to change the call sqlsrv_execute to sqlsrv_query

There's an example of looping through a SQL result set here [PHP MSSQL - How To Loop through Returning Rows?](http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/sql_server_2/PHP_mssql_fetch_array_Looping_through_Returning_Rows.html)

Hope that helps

Comment: thank for replying, but how could i get that resultset and print it out

Comment: it keep returning: The active result for the query contains no fields. weird, seem like it just return boolean.

Comment: fetch from query select or sumthing like that i run without any problem, just SP that i cant fetch anything from it.

Comment: I don't know PHP that well, but according to the documentation, sqlsrv_execute returns a bool [sqlsrv_execute](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-execute.php) not a array

Comment: sadly i dont have SP code, chief just give me db that already have it.

Comment: a yeah, i saw it, return boolean if using execute. maybe i should try with query

Comment: Did this solve your problem? Please mark this as the answer if it did.

Comment: sadly no, maybe it just 'cause of SP, anyway thank for ur reply

Answer (score 0):

You need to change code as i mention below.
use stmp as argument to method sqlsrv_fetch_array .

```
if(sqlsrv_execute($smtp)){
     print "success";
    while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($smtp)){
        print_r($row);
        print "<br />";
    }
}else{
    print_r( sqlsrv_errors());
}
```

if you still not able to do it let me know what problem you are facing with this code.